# Adding a Ansible variable to Cassandra config template Yaml

Tags: cassandra, automation, ansible, ansible-template

I'm using Ansible to setup an AWS Cassandra cluster and I'm trying to pass the dynamic IPs to a YML template file.  I have the IPs assigned to an Ansible group variable and want to use this when populating my Cassandra config YML.  In `Play 1` I initially assign the group like:

```
file : roles/gather_cassandra_hosts/tasks/main.yml

- name: Setup hosts for Cassandra nodes
  add_host: hostname={{ node.public_dns_name }} groups=cassandraNodes
```

Then in `Play 2` I am trying to use this variable to set the following standard Cassandra config:

```
file : roles/install_cassandra/tasks/main.yml

- name: Override cassandra.yaml file
  template:
    src: cassandra.yaml
    dest: apache-cassandra-3.11.3/conf/
  with_items:
    - cassandraNodes
```

.

```
file : roles/install_cassandra/templates/cassandra.yaml

listen_address: {{ cassandraNodes }}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
failed: [ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.region-1.compute.amazonaws.com] (item=cassandraNodes) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": "cassandraNodes",
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'cassandraNodes' is undefined"
}
```

At the beginning I am able to use `cassandraNodes` just fine to define my nodes...

```
- name: Play 2. Install Cassandra
  hosts: cassandraNodes
```

...but it's just this substitution in the template that doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what worked for me was to define another variable in the `vars` section for `Play 2`, and pass that value to the template:

Playbook:

```
vars:
  nodes: "{{ groups['cassandraNodes'] }}"
```

Role:

```
- name: Override cassandra.yaml file
  template:
    src: cassandra.yaml
    dest: apache-cassandra-3.11.3/conf/
  with_items:
  - nodes
```

Template:

```
listen_address: {{ nodes }}
```